# BitmapDecoder .GetPixelDataAsync(params) changing the orientation of captured image

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, uwp, windows-10-universal, windows-10-mobile, uwp-xaml

I am working with an UWP app and facing an issue while displaying a camera captured image(Portrait) in an image control.If I use parmaterized version

```
       decoder.GetPixelDataAsync(
               BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8, // WriteableBitmap uses BGRA format 
               BitmapAlphaMode.Ignore,
               transform,
               ExifOrientationMode.IgnoreExifOrientation, // This sample ignores Exif orientation 
               ColorManagementMode.DoNotColorManage);
```

The outcome is image with change in orientation of 90 degree in anticlock direction. //Issue
[image: oriented image] Oriented            [image: normal] Normal

However default `decoder.GetPixelDataAsync();`works fine.

Problem here is I cannot use default version of GetPixelDataSync() as I need to scale the image using BitmapTransformation.

Please help.

Complete Code:

```
public async Task PrepareCapturedImage(StorageFile originalFile)
    {
        try
        {
            BitmapImage capturedImage_ = new BitmapImage();
            BitmapDecoder decoder = null;
            // the image is sometimes not created and we are trying to access it
            await Task.Delay(300);
            using (IRandomAccessStream stream = await originalFile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read))
            {
                capturedImage_.SetSource(stream);
                decoder = await BitmapDecoder.CreateAsync(stream);
            }

            BitmapTransform transform = new BitmapTransform();
            uint newHeight = Convert.ToUInt32(capturedImage_.PixelHeight);
            uint newWidth = Convert.ToUInt32(capturedImage_.PixelWidth);

            transform.ScaledHeight = newHeight;
            transform.ScaledWidth = newWidth;

            PixelDataProvider pixelData = await decoder.GetPixelDataAsync(
                   BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8, // WriteableBitmap uses BGRA format 
                   BitmapAlphaMode.Ignore,
                   transform,
                   ExifOrientationMode.IgnoreExifOrientation, // This sample ignores Exif orientation 
                   ColorManagementMode.DoNotColorManage);

            // An array containing the decoded image data, which could be modified before being displayed 
            byte[] sourcePixels = pixelData.DetachPixelData();

            using (InMemoryRandomAccessStream ras = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream())
            {
                BitmapEncoder enc = null;
                BitmapPropertySet propertySet = new BitmapPropertySet();


                enc = await BitmapEncoder.CreateAsync(BitmapEncoder.JpegEncoderId, ras, propertySet);
                // write the pixel data to our stream 
                enc.SetPixelData(decoder.BitmapPixelFormat, decoder.BitmapAlphaMode, newWidth, newHeight, decoder.DpiX, decoder.DpiY, sourcePixels);
                await enc.FlushAsync();
                ras.Seek(0);
                BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage();
                image.SetSource(ras);
                cameraOutputImage.Source = image;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
    }
```

Comment: Testing your code with a normal image file, it works fine, so I think the problem is related to your image file captured by camera. Have you checked the orientation of original image file? What device did you use to test your code? Or maybe you can share your sample so can we test on Lumia 640 and 950XL;.

Comment: Orientation of original image is Rotate270. If I set the rotation to 270 in BitmapTransformation and use flag "RespectExifOrientation" it gives the same result. I am using Lumia 950. I have attached the project here [link](https://1drv.ms/u/s!Aue9wofOKdAbh5owPgswQXKjwKEjvQ)